# SQL join two tables with null values in either table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having some trouble joining the contents of two tables. Here's the current situation:

**Bought**
<kbd>**Article**</kbd>   <kbd>**Bought**</kbd> <kbd>**Year**</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>12400</kbd>    <kbd>2011</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>28000</kbd>    <kbd>2012</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>46351</kbd>    <kbd>2015</kbd>

**Sold**
<kbd>**Article**</kbd>   <kbd>**Sold**</kbd>      <kbd>**Year**</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>6400</kbd>      <kbd>2011</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>12000</kbd>    <kbd>2013</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>60900</kbd>    <kbd>2014</kbd>

**Desired Result**
<kbd>**Article**</kbd>   <kbd>**Bought**</kbd> <kbd>**Sold**</kbd>    <kbd>**Year**</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>12400</kbd>    <kbd>6400</kbd>    <kbd>2011</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>28000</kbd>    <kbd>NULL</kbd>   <kbd>2012</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>NULL</kbd>     <kbd>12000</kbd>  <kbd>2013</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>NULL</kbd>     <kbd>60900</kbd>  <kbd>2014</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>46351</kbd>    <kbd>NULL</kbd>   <kbd>2015</kbd>

I've tried the following to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT b.article, b.bought, s.sold, b.year
FROM Bought AS b
  LEFT JOIN Sold as s ON s.article = b.article AND s.year = b.year
WHERE b.article = '1'
ORDER BY b.year
```

This only returns the result for 2011 (Where both values are present).

Another try using a third table holding all articles returned the same bad result and it has two year columns which is not ideal:

```
SELECT art.article, b.bought, s.sold, b.year, s.year
FROM articles AS art
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bought AS b ON art.article = b.article
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Sold AS s ON art.article = s.article
     AND (b.year = s.year OR b.year IS NULL OR s.year IS NULL)
 WHERE art.article = '1'
```

I've tried using different kinds of joins with the last SQL statement but none of them seem to work.
How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: You first query has v.artk in the WHERE, but there are no v table...

Comment: Did you come up with formatting your query results via `<kbd>` or is this something that has already been done here?

Comment: @PeterLang found it as the third answer in this thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: @MrBunni: Interesting, thanks! Looks cumbersome to align the columns though...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `full outer join`:

```
SELECT coalesce(b.article, s.article) as article, b.bought, s.sold,
       coalesce(b.year, s.year) as year
FROM Bought b FULL OUTER JOIN
     Sold s
     ON s.article = b.article AND s.year = b.year
WHERE (b.article = '1' OR s.article = '1')
ORDER BY year
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `full outer join` :

```
select coalesce(b.article, s.article)
     , b.bought
     , s.sold
     , coalesce (b.year, s.year) as year
from Bought b
full join Sold s on s.article = b.article
                 and s.year = b.year
where coalesce(b.article, s.article) = '1'
order by year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an union. First select with left join and then union the sold results that don't have corresponding rows in bought.

```
SELECT b.article, b.bought, s.sold, b.year
FROM Bought AS b
LEFT JOIN Sold as s ON s.article = b.article AND s.year = b.year
where article = 1
Union 
SELECT article,null, sold, year
FROM sold where article =1 and year not in (select year from bought)
```

Something like that. I haven't tested it but you can get the idea.